# Creating a simple code for transforming my dataset in R, from wide to long

Tags: r, transformation

this may be a simple question, but I don't have a knack for writing code in R AT ALL.
I have a dataset with right censoring that looks something like this:

```
dput(head(books)):

structure(list(id = 1:6, time = c(29, 30, 26, 30, 30, 29
), event = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1), z1 = c("early", "late", 
"early", "late", "late", "early"), z2 = c(9, 6, 4, 9, 
9, 5), z3 = c(0B, 1B, 0C, 0C, 0C, 0C), burrowed = c(1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1), time.burrowed = c(5, 2, 6, 30, 1, 8), 
    returned = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), time.returned = c(20, 30, 21, 
    30, 28, 29)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

and I need it to look like this?

```
head(books)

id     start     stop     checkedout     event     z1     z2
1       0         5           0           0       early   9
1       5        20           1           0       early   9
1      20        30           0           1       early   9   etc.
2    
3
4
4
```

basically, combining the borrowed and returned into whether it's checked out at these times or not

I have so far...

```
    start <- 0
     stop <- numeric(length=0)
     checkedout <- 0
     event <- numeric(length=0)
     if (book$burrowed[1]==1) {
     start <- c(start, book$time.burrowed[1])
     stop <- c(stop, book$time.burrowed[1])
     checkedout <- c(checkedout,1)
     event <- c(event, 0)
     }
     if (book$returned[1]==1) {
     start <- c(start, book$time.returned[1])
     stop <- c(stop, book$time.returned[1])
     checkedout <- c(checkedout,0)
     event <- c(event, 0)
     }
     stop <- c(stop, book$time[1])
     event <- c(event, book$event[1])
     temp.frame <- data.frame(id=book$id[1],start,stop,event,checkedout)
```

Comment: Can you post minimal examples of data, it will help full to better understanding.

Comment: i edited the question, is that better?

Comment: To share data, try something like `dput(head(book))` and edit your question with the results. Then, also show based on your data what you would expect for the first few rows of your desired/target data frame. That would be very helpful.

Comment: OK, I tried editing it again. Thanks for the tip, this is my first post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for providing the data, it is helpful. However, there still is uncertainty on how you want to set specific columns, such as `event` (it appears different between the result from your code, and the example above).

Here's something that might help you get started. I am guessing you'll want to add specific conditional rules to help further shape how your result looks.

First, I would create a function to handle a single row of data:

```
my_fun <- function(x) {
  df <- as.data.frame(rbind(
    c(id = x[["id"]], start = 0, stop = x[["time.burrowed"]], event = 0, checkedout = 0),
    c(id = x[["id"]], start = x[["time.burrowed"]], stop = x[["time.returned"]], event = 0, checkedout = 1),
    c(id = x[["id"]], start = x[["time.returned"]], stop = x[["time"]], event = x[["event"]], checkedout = 0)
  ))
  df <- cbind(
    df,
    z1 = x[["z1"]],
    z2 = x[["z2"]],
    z3 = x[["z3"]]
  )
  return(df)
}
```

In this function, you can clearly indicate what you want in converting a single row to three rows of data. Specifically, indicate what the `start` and `stop` should be based on `time.burrowed` (misspelling?) and `time.returned`. Also, you can hard code the first `start` as 0, and final `stop` as `time`. Here, you can also indicate what you want for `event` and `checkedout`. I set `event` to 0 based on your example code for the first two rows, and then `event` for third row; and `checkedout` was 1 only for middle row. In the end, the three rows are combined with `rbind`.

After that, other columns can be added with `cbind`. This includes `z1`, `z2`, etc. which appear constant across rows.

You can try out the function with a single row, such as:

```
R> my_fun(book[1,])
  id start stop event checkedout    z1 z2 z3
1  1     0    5     0          0 early  9 0B
2  1     5   20     0          1 early  9 0B
3  1    20   29     1          0 early  9 0B
```

Once you are satisfied with your function, you can apply the function to all rows in your data frame:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(1:nrow(book), function(x) my_fun(book[x,])))
```

**Output**

```
   id start stop event checkedout    z1 z2 z3
1   1     0    5     0          0 early  9 0B
2   1     5   20     0          1 early  9 0B
3   1    20   29     1          0 early  9 0B
4   2     0    2     0          0  late  6 1B
5   2     2   30     0          1  late  6 1B
6   2    30   30     0          0  late  6 1B
7   3     0    6     0          0 early  4 0C
8   3     6   21     0          1 early  4 0C
9   3    21   26     1          0 early  4 0C
10  4     0   30     0          0  late  9 0C
11  4    30   30     0          1  late  9 0C
12  4    30   30     0          0  late  9 0C
13  5     0    1     0          0  late  9 0C
14  5     1   28     0          1  late  9 0C
15  5    28   30     0          0  late  9 0C
16  6     0    8     0          0 early  5 0C
17  6     8   29     0          1 early  5 0C
18  6    29   29     1          0 early  5 0C
```